# Get the value of an Excel cell using a Range object

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a VB.Net function in an Excel addin that I need to find the first occurrence of a string in a worksheet, then return the entire value of the cell. For example, if cell F4 contains "apples and oranges", then Findit("apples") should find a range of $F$4, and return "apples and oranges".

In the code below, I'm getting the correct range stored in MatchedRange, but I can't figure out how to use that to get the value of that cell. I know I need to make the cell active, but that's where I'm struggling.

```
Private Sub FixFormulasButton_OnClick(sender As Object, control As IRibbonControl, pressed As     Boolean) Handles FixFormulasButton.OnClick
        Dim ws As Object = CType(ExcelApp.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim cells As Object = ws.Cells
        Dim MatchRange As Object = CType(cells.Find("apples", LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,     Lookin:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas), Excel.Range)

        If MatchRange Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("found no apples", "do nothing", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(the contents of the cell at the range found above)
        End if
End Sub
```

Comment: I take it `MatchRange.Value` doesn't work?